# Multer.Multer middleware isn't responce/working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I was trying to save imgs into mongodb using multer and multer-gridfs-storage.Every time I'm trying to upload imgs with request I get undefined and I also have couple of console logs into middleware but they aren't working as multer itself.Names of files are the same whether it's front/back

```
express
let conn = mongoose.connection;

//-----------Multer--------------

conn.once('open', () => {
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: process.env.MONGO_URI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    console.log(file, 'file from multer');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads',
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
        console.log(fileInfo, 'file info from GridFs');
      });
    });
  },
});

const upload = multer({storage});

//--------------Routes
router.post(
  '/api/profile/upload/avatar',
  upload.single('downloadAvatar'),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files, 'req.files');
  }
);
```

```
React
      <form
        action='/api/profile/upload/avatar'
        className='downloadButton'
        encType='multipart/form-data'
      >
        <label htmlFor='downloadAvatar'>
          <AddIcon></AddIcon>
          <input
            name='downloadAvatar'
            id='downloadAvatar'
            type='file'
            accept='image/'
            style={{display: 'none'}}
            onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files)}
          />
        </label>
      </form>

export const uploadAvatar = (file) => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await api.post('/api/profile/upload/avatar', file);
  console.log(res.data, 'data action ');
  dispatch({type: types.UPLOAD_AVATAR, payload: res.data});
};
```